# angular material: extend a MatPaginator without creating a dupe paginator

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, angular-material2

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-custom-paginator',
    template: '<mat-paginator #paginator pageSize="10"></mat-paginator>',
    })
export class CustomPaginator extends MatPaginator {
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

    customMethod(): number {
        return 1
    }
}
```

main component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-main-component',
    template: '<app-custom-paginator></app-custom-paginator>',
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild(CustomPaginator) paginator: CustomPaginator;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to extend `MatPaginator`.  I'm stuck because in my child component `CustomPaginator`, i'm having to use `@ViewChild` to gain access to the created `MatPaginator` that that custom paginator created from its view.

What I really want is to somehow create a `CustomPaginator` from my `MainComponent` without the `CustomPaginator` needing to create and access a `MatPaginator` view child of its own, since `CustomPaginator` IS a `MatPaginator`.

Comment: It's better to take a look at the Angular Material site first, https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/examples#paginator-intl

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MatPaginator component's template inside child component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-custom-paginator',
    template: (<any>MatPaginator).__annotations__[0]['template'],
})
export class CustomPaginator extends MatPaginator {

    customMethod(): number {
        return 1
    }
}
```

I had done these with custom base components never used on material components. you can try

Answer (score 0):

To make your CustomPaginator work, you have to call the super constructor :

```js
import {MatPaginator, MatPaginatorIntl} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

// ...

export class CustomPaginator extends MatPaginator {

    constructor(
        intl: MatPaginatorIntl,
        changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    ) {
        super(intl, changeDetectorRef);
    }

}
```